# How can I securely give one public IP address access to my [big org] intranet anonymous non-ssl web application?

Tags: iis, networking, routes, url-rewriting, infrastructure

1. I have an anonymous non-SSL web application on my Intranet. Url is http://WebSerPro/OutageDash. This application has ajax to refresh its update panel and is sessionless.
2. I want to expose just this http://WebSerPro/OutageDash?Sections=Limited to an external source which has public ip 1.1.1.1.
3. Source is only allowed to do post/get to our gateway having global ip 2.2.2.2
4. I want SSL, https and user authentication (user/pw) between 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2
5. I want only one instance of my web aplicatiuon running (database hit is fixed to once per minutes).

How can I do that ?

Comment: this sounds infrastructure/network related and not programming related to me

Comment: Thanks I changes the tags accordingly. As a developer I often overlook that and only see coding/configuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 [IIS] sites (one http, one https), make them point to the same web application. In the application, behave according  to source ip or site used to reach the application.